# jQuery of Dialog and datepicker

Tags: jquery-ui

```
$(function(){
                // Dialog
                $('#dialog').dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 600,
                buttons: {
                    "Ok": function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    "Cancel": function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });

            // Dialog Link
            $('#dialog_link').click(function(){
                $('#dialog').dialog('open');
                return false;
            });

            //hover states on the static widgets
            $('#dialog_link, ul#icons li').hover(
                function() { $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover'); },
                function() { $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover'); }
            );

        });
```

i m use dialog box jquery in which i want use datepicker 
it show me outsde of the dialog box.....thats problem....

```
    <div id="dialog" title="Find Patient">
      <p>
      <table style="table-layout: fixed; width: 550px;">
        <tr>
          <td><label class="form-item-label form-item-label-right">Patient Id :</label> </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="byId" id="byId" style="width: 90%"  /></td>
           <td><a class="button" href="#"><span>Find</span></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label class="form-item-label form-item-label-right">Patient`s Name :</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="byName" id="byName" style="width: 90%"/></td>
            <td><a class="button" href="#"><span>Find</span></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="dob" name="dob" style="width: 90%"></td>
            <td><a class="button" href="#"><span>Find</span></a></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
      </p>
    </div>
```

when i m use the datepicker Jquery in last row of table in dialog box 
load my html page Datepicker is load on page first

Comment: i call datepicker function onfocus of #dob. so datepicker is come in page not in dialog box...Now that problem....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know if this is your solution, but try this out if you are tend to use the Jquery datepicker you should add it to the element directly on load mabye and not on focus, it will append when you focus the textbox anyway. Notice the line of code `$('#dob').datepicker();`

```
$(function () {
    // Dialog
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 600,
        buttons: {
            "Ok": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });

    $('#dob').datepicker();

    // Dialog Link
    $('#dialog_link').click(function () {
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        return false;
    });

    //hover states on the static widgets
    $('#dialog_link, ul#icons li').hover(
            function () { $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover'); },
            function () { $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover'); }
        );

});
```

Comment: i m use 
 $(function() {
    $("#dob").datepicker();
    $("#dob").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", 'dd-mm-yy');

   });

Comment: that problem is solve but 
in Dialog Box I have put two button Ok and cancel are
both name is not display in the dialog box both r working but name is not display.......

Comment: Plz help ..please give me a demo of jquery  for like this http://www.orthoimplantcompany.com/products/